# Persist user profile into cookie when using ASP.NET.Identity

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-identity

When using forms authentication, we can persist anything we want into cookie by User Data. Now, I'm trying to use ASP.NET.Identity which almost has done everything related to Authentication for us. But it seems that it hasn't provide us a way to persist arbitrary User Data into cookie. Or maybe it is that I did not find it.
    Can any one help me?
    Thanks in advance, and sorry for my poor English.

Comment: so whynot create your own cookie ?

Comment: @philsoady. thank you for your comment. I want to use something like UserData in Forms Authentication just because I want to make the code looks a little more consistent..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET Identity provides support for Claims. You can utilize adding claims of profile information to the signin identity.

This is an example only.

```
var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("ProfileDATA", "VALUE"));
AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
```

Comment: Hi @jd4u, thanks for your anwser. I use your code, and I can get the added claims by `HttpContext.User`. But I am not sure if the claims have been persisted into cookies. Could you eliminate my confusion? Thanks again.

Comment: Claims added to Identity persists in cookies.

Comment: Is profile data an appropriate use for claims? I think of claims as pieces of data related to the identity of a user that can be used for authentication or authorization, where profile data can be user preferences within the app, or other non-identifying information about the user.